# Fixed header bar on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, css-position

I am using wordpress to develop a site with link at [here](http://hkicc.hkcs.org.hk/). I would like to fix the position of the header bar so even I scroll down, the header bar will continue to display.

[Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25309660/) is my original css file. I have tried to add css {position:fixed} to .header; however, it is not working. May anyone please help for the issue?

Thanks

Comment: clear your cache mate, Ctr + F5/Shift + F5, it's working fine

Comment: Works in Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Oh yea, right. Thanks